# Google Geocoding API - Notifications

Tags: google-maps, google-geocoding-api

I'm using the following API in one of my applications.
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/output?parameters

XML configured output is being used. I would like to know if there is any way I can get the following information.

1. Are there any chances that this API may be shut down in future?
2. Is there an option to register using my email address so that notifications on upgrade or shutdown are received?
3. As this seems to be a free service, will this be converted to a paid version in future?

Answer (score 0):

I would answer your question one by one..

1. It will be deprecated in the future as with most Google API's but the old api will be supported for quite some time. For eg.. Maps API V2 is [now deprecated](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/)
2. If you read the [Usage Limits](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/) you will come to know the this service is free for 2500 request per day for a normal user.
3. It is a combination of free and paid service based on usage. (2500 request per day is free)
   After that it will be blocked unless you pay.

Comment: Thanks for the details! Just one more generic question.. Will there be any notification posted in advance if the API support is to be stopped? This will give us some time in looking for an alternative.

Comment: I am not sure of the notification stuff but it will surely show deprecated on the website.. don't worry even after it become deprecated it will still be supported for a few years